# Is there a word or phrase describing a tree in winter with all its leaves fallen off?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word or phrase describing a tree in winter with all its leaves fallen off? It makes me look at it in awe.

Comment: Trees which have lost heir leaves in winter are often said to be [naked](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2021/dec/23/the-naked-mystery-of-the-winter-tree) or [bare](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2024/jan/29/country-diary-why-do-we-stare-at-bare-winter-trees) (two _Guardian_ Nature Diary columns). There are other adjectives, 'dormant is one. Deciduous trees are _denudate_ in the winter (and winter is _denudative_). A tree can become denudate from normal seasonal leaf loss, or to abnormal leaf loss from defoliants, infestations or droughts.

Comment: https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45099/sonnet-73-that-time-of-year-thou-mayst-in-me-behold

Comment: A good start to answering this question would be to use a bilingual dictionary. Alternatively you could use translation software in combination with your dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

A tree *loses* its leaves, so  it's quite common to say *“the trees **have lost** all their leaves”*. The verb *shed* is sometimes used instead, so we get *“the trees **have shed** all their leaves”*.

Meanwhile the  adjective ***bare*** describes a tree, in winter, without its leaves. In my opinion, *bare* is preferable to the accurate descriptor *leafless* which resonates with *lifeless*, a tree without life.

However, a Google Books Ngram shows that the expression *leafless trees* was once hugely popular in *print*, and was only overtaken by *bare trees* in the mid 1930s. Nonetheless both variants continue to dominate over the phrase *naked trees*.

[image]

- [Why do trees shed their leaves](https://https:/https://earthsky.org/earth/why-do-trees-shed-their-leaves/)?
- [Why Do Trees Lose Their Leaves?](https://www.thespruce.com/why-do-trees-lose-their-leaves-6826069)

> We look forward to the colorful display they put on during the fall foliage season just before the leaves drop, but we spend the next several months looking at stark, **bare branches**.
> Source: *The Spruce*

> One of the landscapes she captured was this stark forest - an endless array of **bare tree trunks** and branches.
> **Bare trees** drum their knobbly branches menacingly on the windows.
>
> Source: *Sunday Times*

> He walked to the window and looked out at the snowy mountain. The **leafless trees** and the snow covered slopes were bleak, cold, and forbidding, but they were beautiful to him. So were the white fields and the red barn that stood out sharply against the grey sky.
> Source: *Wild Dogs of the Sourland* by Keith Robertson